# Sqlacodegen generates mixed models and tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlacodegen

Executing this command:

```
sqlacodegen <connection-url> --outfile db.py
```

The db.py contains generated tables:

```
t_table1 = Table(...)
```

and classes too:

```
Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
```

The problem is that a table is generated in one way only - either a table or a class.

I would like to make it generate models (classes) only but in the provided flags I couldn't find such an option. Any idea?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like what you're describing is a feature itself. `sqlacodegen`will not always generate class models.

It will *only form model classes for tables that have a primary key and are not association tables*, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen/blob/master/sqlacodegen/codegen.py#L354):

```py
# Only form model classes for tables that have a primary key and are not association tables
if noclasses or not table.primary_key or table.name in association_tables:
    model = self.table_model(table)
else:
    model = self.class_model(table, links[table.name], self.inflect_engine, not nojoined)
    classes[model.name] = model
```

Furthermore, in the [documentation](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen/) it is stated that

> A table is considered an association table if it satisfies all of the
>   following conditions:
>
> 1. has exactly two foreign key constraints
> 2. all its columns are involved in said constraints

Although, you can try a quick and dirty hack. Locate those lines in the source code (something like `/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlacodegen/codegen.py`) and comment out the first three code lines (and fix indentation):

```py
# Only form model classes for tables that have a primary key and are not association tables
# if noclasses or not table.primary_key or table.name in association_tables:
#    model = self.table_model(table)
# else:
model = self.class_model(table, links[table.name], self.inflect_engine, not nojoined)
classes[model.name] = model
```

I have tried this for one specific table that was generated as a table model. It went from

```py
t_Admin_op = Table(
    'Admin_op', metadata,
    Column('id_admin', Integer, nullable=False),
    Column('id_op', Integer, nullable=False)
)
```

to

```py
class AdminOp(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Admin_op'

    id_admin = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    id_op = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

You can also open an issue about this as a feature request, in the [official tracker](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/sqlacodegen/issues).

Just in case, if you want the opposite (only table models), you could do so with the `--noclasses` flag.

Comment: SQLAlchemy requires a primary key for each mapped class so even if there was such an option, the generated model code would not work.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm so what is the best practice for accessing existing tables without primary keys in sqlalchemy?

Comment: You can use the Table objects (the SQLAlchemy docs should cover this), they just can't be mapped as classes.